# Get current UserID in ASP.NET and insert into Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Apologies for being an extreme beginner. I'm trying to get an insert query to work but include the current UserId as one of the fields.

From looking online the current code I have on the aspx.cs file:

```
AccessDataSource2.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [aspnet_ActivityBooking] ([BookingDate],[BookingTime], [NoOfPeople], [UserId], [Facility_Id]) VALUES (@Date, @Time, @People, @UserId, 1);";
AccessDataSource2.Insert();
AccessDataSource2.DataBind();

txtDate.Text = Profile.Date;
txtTime.Text = Profile.Time;
txtPeople.Text = Profile.People;
TextBox1.Text = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

And on the AccessDataSource insert query on the aspx page:

```
INSERT INTO [aspnet_ActivityBooking] ( [BookingDate], [BookingTime], [NoOfPeople], [UserId], [Facility_Id]) VALUES (@Date, @Time, @People, @UserId, 1)
```

I have three text boxes for user entry, Date, Time and People.

The table I'm trying to insert into looks like this:

Booking_ID,
BookingDate,
BookingTime,
NoOfPeople,
UserId,
Facility_Id,

When I try to input an entry I get this error:

OLEDBEXCEPTION was unhandled by user code
Data mismatch type in criteria expression

I'd appreciate any help thanks.

Update:

Here's the code I have for the aspx page:

```
 <br />
  <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<table style="width: 100%" id="table">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 134px; height: 22px;">Booking Date&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 22px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ontextchanged="txtDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;(dd/mm/yyyy)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 134px">Booking Time</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;(eg. 22:24 or 10:24pm)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 134px">Number of People</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPeople" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 134px">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
```

```
            <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" />

        </td>
    </tr>

     </table>



  <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
      DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" 
      InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [aspnet_ActivityBooking] ( [BookingDate], [BookingTime], [NoOfPeople], [UserId], [Facility_Id]) VALUES (@Date, @Time, @People, @UserId, 1)" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT aspnet_ActivityBooking.Booking_ID, aspnet_ActivityBooking.BookingDate, aspnet_ActivityBooking.BookingTime, aspnet_ActivityBooking.NoOfPeople, aspnet_ActivityBooking.UserId, aspnet_ActivityBooking.Facility_Id FROM ((aspnet_ActivityBooking INNER JOIN asnet_Facility ON aspnet_ActivityBooking.Facility_Id = asnet_Facility.Facility_ID) INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_ActivityBooking.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId)">
      <InsertParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDate" Name="Date" PropertyName="Text" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTime" Name="Time" PropertyName="Text" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPeople" Name="People" PropertyName="Text" />
          <asp:ProfileParameter Name="UserName" PropertyName="UserId" />

          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="UserId" PropertyName="Text" />



      </InsertParameters>
  </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns you are trying to insert into? `.Text` will always return `String`

Comment: Hi. Booking_ID is 'Autonumber'. BookingDate, BookingTime and NoOfPeople are 'Text'. UserId and Facility_Id are Number.

Comment: I understand that this is slightly irrelevant, but why are you storing BookingDate as text and not date/time, BookingTime as text and not date/time and NoOfPeople as Text and not as number? you will not be able to do any meaningful searches or operations on your DB. Have a look here if you need any more info on column types supported in MS Access : http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-HA010233292.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `TextBox.Text` property, the returned value is always a `String`. Hence, when you try to insert the value for user ID directly as `TextBox1.Text`, you are trying to insert a String value into a Numeric column. You could try to convert it to an `int` first, using `TryParse` method as follows:

```
int userid = 0;
bool isUserIDInt = int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out userid);
```

Then assign `userid` to the `@UserID` parameter.

Comment: Do I delete this line: TextBox1.Text = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;   And where would the parse code go? I tried putting it under the other lines and still get the OLEDBEXCEPTION error on the AccessDataSource2.Insert(); line.

Comment: From your insert query, it looks like you are using parametrised queries. Can you please post the code where you assign values to parameters? That is where this parse code should be present.

Comment: This code?

  <InsertParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDate" Name="Date" PropertyName="Text" />
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTime" Name="Time" PropertyName="Text" />
              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPeople" Name="People" PropertyName="Text" />
              <asp:ProfileParameter Name="UserName" PropertyName="UserId" />

              <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="UserId" PropertyName="Text" />       </InsertParameters>

Comment: Can you please add this data to your question instead of in comment?

Comment: Ok, I've added it to the question.